# Algorithm that decides whether collection of primes exists which satisfies 3 equations

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

Suppose someone gives you a list of $n$ positive numbers $(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$, together with an upper limit $N$ and asks you to find prime numbers $p_1, \ldots ,p_n$ in the range $2, \ldots , N$ satisfying

$p_2 = p_1 + a_1$ and $p_3 = p_2 + a_2$ ... and ... $p_n = p_{n-1} + a_{n-1}$

How do you write down a general algorithm for deciding whether or not collection of prime numbers $(p_1, \ldots , p_n)$ exists that satisfies these 3 equations?

What will it look like?

Comment: The way you are formulating this question, since our initial set goes up to $a_n$, don't we only need to find primes $p_1, \dotsc, p_{n-1}$? Also the title and your post says "3 equation" however it looks like we have $n-1$ equations. You should edit your post to clarify these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudo-code for my brutish approach to it.

```
Let A = {a1, a2, ..., an}
Let sieve = {p | p is prime and less than N}
If ((size of sieve < size of A) OR (some a[i] == 1 for i > 1))
    return False;
Let primeDiffs = {sieve[i] - sieve[i-1] | i in [2..(size of sieve)]}
For i in [1..(size of primeDiffs - size of A)] {
    For j in [1..(size of A)] {
        If(A[j] /= primeDiffs[i+j])
            continue
    }
    return True
}
return False
```

Essentially just generate all the primes that you need, build the set of the consecutive differences of those primes, and iterate over that set seeing if all of your set $\{a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n\}$ matches your current position in the set of differences.

You can do some clever checking on the $\{a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n\}$ set at the start like make sure none of $\{a_2, a_3 \dotsc, a_n\}$ are $1$ (the only primes with a difference of $1$ are $2$ and $3$).